# Doubt regarding Fermat's principle

Tags: optics, visible-light, boundary-conditions, variational-principle, causality

Which two points are we talking about in Fermat's principle? Are those points decided by light or decided by us? Can we take any two points?

Comment: Hi Kiran. While the question I have linked is a duplicate it's quite technical and you my find it impenetrable. If so ping me here and I'll reopen this question so someone can add a simpler answer.

Comment: Fermat's principle states that given *any* two points $P$ and $Q$ between which there *is* a ray then the optical path length defined by $[OPL]= \int_{P}^{Q}nds$ is extremum among all neighboring paths connecting the fixed points $P$ and $Q$.